# debian packaging control file

Tags: debian, packaging

In creating a debian package with an application for a desktop user, what 'section' do I use in the debian control file?

All the ones I find seem to be system level, or developer oriented, not end user.

In the desktop file I am using 'Office'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's helpful, [Section 5.7 of the Debian Developer's Reference](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/pkgs.html#override-file) says:

> The debian/control file's Section and Priority fields do not actually specify where the file will be placed in the archive, nor its priority. In order to retain the overall integrity of the archive, it is the archive maintainers who have control over these fields. The values in the debian/control file are actually just hints.

You could omit the section or just use *misc* (found in [Section 2.4 of the Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#s-subsections)) until you come up with something better.